# How to implement summation in GAMS

Tags: optimization, model, sum

I would like to implement the sum in equation number 10 as presented in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUgz1.png) using GAMS.  Knowing that P is a Power vector and hij is a square matrix. If I am going to use matlab I would implement it as following

sinr = (P .* hj) ./ (sigma2 + hij' * P);

I would be really thankful for any advices and hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ax` is written in GAMS as `sum(j, A(i,j)*x(j))`. Of course transposing `A` is easy: `A'x` is written as `sum(j, A(j,i)*x(j))`

Comment: Thx for your reply really thx.  I want to confirm a final thing and for output value it will be a vector and i should put for example sinr[i] no ?